# SQL Server 2014 excluding rows

Tags: sql-server-2014, rows, common-table-expression

My query:

```
`SELECT gft_key,
DonorCustomer.cst_ind_full_name_dn as 'Full Name',
DonorCustomer.cst_ixo_title_dn as 'Job Title',
DonorCustomer.cst_org_name_dn as 'Organization',
DonorCustomer.cst_eml_address_dn as 'Email Address',
apl_code as 'Appeal Code',
cmp_code as 'Campaign Code',
prd_name as 'Product Name',
chp_name as 'Chapter Name',
adr_line1,
adr_line2,
adr_city as 'City',
adr_post_code as 'Zip Code',
adr_country as 'Country',
mem_member_type as 'Member Type',
ivd_amount_cp as 'Gift Amount',
fun_code as 'Purpose Code',
gty_type as 'Gift Type',
gft_date as 'Gift Date',
pay_trx_date,
case 
when pay_trx_date is null then 'Not Paid' else 'Paid' end as 'Paid?'
FROM 
np_gift  
JOIN np_gift_type ON gft_gty_key=gty_key 
JOIN np_constituent ON gft_dnr_cst_key=dnr_cst_key 
JOIN co_customer DonorCustomer ON dnr_cst_key=DonorCustomer.cst_key 
JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cst_cxa_key = cxa_key 
JOIN co_address ON cxa_adr_key = adr_key 
JOIN oe_product ON gft_fpc_prd_key=prd_key 
LEFT JOIN np_purpose ON gft_fun_key=fun_key 
LEFT JOIN np_campaign ON gft_cmp_key=cmp_key 
LEFT JOIN np_appeal ON gft_apl_key=apl_key 
JOIN ac_invoice_detail ON gft_ivd_key=ivd_key and ivd_void_flag=0 
left outer join ac_payment_detail on pyd_ivd_key=ivd_key
left outer join ac_payment on pyd_pay_key=pay_key 
left outer join ac_payment_info on pay_pin_key=pin_key
LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type ON dnr_cst_key=mem_cst_key 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_customer ON cxc_cst_key_1 = DonorCustomer.cst_key and (cxc_end_date is null or datediff(dd,getdate(),cxc_end_date) >=0) and cxc_rlt_code='Chapter Member' 
LEFT JOIN co_chapter ON cxc_cst_key_2=chp_cst_key 
where (pay_trx_date >= '7/1/2017' or pay_trx_date is null)
order by gft_date`
```

Sample data that I get by running the query: `Gift Date    pay_trx_date
                                            2013-11-18    2017-07-12
                                            2013-11-29    NULL
                                            2014-12-15    NULL
                                            2017-06-30    NULL
                                            2015-05-01    2017-07-01`

By running the query above I accomplish the above result set. However, I want to exclude rows where the gift date is < '7/1/2017' and pay_trx_date is NULL (Just like the middle rows in my sample data) at the same time though I want to keep rows where the gift date is <= '7/1/2017' and pay_trx_date is not NULL (Just like the first or last row in my sample data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your current query as inner block and filter one time as per your requirement.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   -- Your Current Query
) Q
WHERE gft_date <= '7/1/2017' AND pay_trx_date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: it won't run. I don't think it makes sense. I need to exclude those rows.

Comment: Can someone help out by looking at the initial question? Thank you.